# Differences between Visual Studio 2010 editions - source saved in different versions

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to open a project that was saved in one edition of VS2010 in another edition of VS2010?

For example. I am working on a C# XNA application that was originally created with VS 2010 Premium. At home I have VS 2010 Ultimate. It gives me the error

```
The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

Is there any way around this, or do I have to install Premium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to go from a reduced version (Premium) to an expanded version (Ultimate) it will work. Everything in Premium is in Ultimate, it's just a matter if you've installed that portion of the expanded version or not. In this case, you probably did not install the C# component of Ultimate. Try "re-installing" Ultimate. (That is, start the installer and select C#)

Comment: I have all the components installed, I use C# regularly. I think I may have forgotten to install VS2010 SP1 on my home workstation. I'm installing it now, I'll report back with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that only problematic thing is some project type that you don't have installed at your Ultimate installation, which btw supports more than premium. So, maybe I guess it can be VB project type and you don't have VB component installed on Ultimate or something ?

Do you have XNA installed correctly, that could also be a problem ?

Try to find a workaround here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/08/30/9889189.aspx